# If 'falsity' belongs to the set of all propositions (PROP) shouldn't '¬ falsity' also belong to PROP?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am a newbie in logic and I am reading the book Logic and Structure by Dirk van Dalen. In the first chapter the author gives the following definition:

Definition 1.1.2: The set PROP of propositions is the smallest set X with the properties

(i) pi ∈ X(i ∈ N), ⊥∈X,

(ii) ϕ,ψ ∈ X ⇒ (ϕ∧ψ), (ϕ∨ψ), (ϕ →ψ), (ϕ ↔ψ)∈X,

(iii) ϕ ∈ X ⇒ (¬ϕ) ∈ X.

I can make sense of (ii) and (iii). (i), however, is not so clear to me. I understand it as 'propositions pi belong to X and ⊥ (falsity) also belongs to X', meaning that it is possible for propositions in X to be false. I know that it doesn't necessarily excludes the possibility of a proposition being ¬⊥, or true, but it also doesn't make this possibility explicit. So my question is... shouldn't it? If it is not necessary to make explicit that veracity is possible in X why is it necessary to do so for falsity?

I apologise if this is too basic a question.

Anyway, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: True and False as truth value are not relevant here: we are defining the *syntax* of the language, i.e. the rule to produce correct (i.e. meaningful) *expressions*. We have to start from a basic set of *symbols*: the propositional variables: $p_1, p_2, \ldots$, the *falsum* sign: $\bot$ and the logical *connectives*: $\lnot, \land, \ldots$.

Comment: Then we define the set $\text{PROP}$ of *propositional formulas*: rule (i) says that the propositional variables $p_i$ as well as *falsum* $\bot$ are propositional formulas. Rule (ii) states how to use *binary* connectives: thus $p_1 \land p_2$ and $p_1 \to \bot$ are examples of formulas, according to rule (ii). Rule (iii) states how to use the unary connective (negation): thus, according to this rule, $\lnot p_1$ and $\lnot \bot$ and $\lnot (p_1 \to \bot)$ are examples of formulas,

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849411/understanding-prop-set-in-the-book-logic-and-structure-van-dalen) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139644/understanding-the-induction-principle-in-mathematical-logic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third rule says that $\phi \in X\to (\neg \phi \in X)$.Since $\bot\in X$ we  have that $(\neg \bot)\in X$.